# Validate input is within a numeric range, possibly a float, using express-validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm trying to validate if the input is an integer or a float within a certain range using [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/). I've tried:

```
check(
      'rating',
      'Rating must be a number between 0 and 5'
).isNumeric({ min: 0, max: 5 }),
```

but the `min` and `max` values don't actually work. I tried putting in numbers above `5` and they don't throw an error.

The code below works, it won't allow numbers outside of the `min` and `max` limits:

```
check(
      'rating',
      'Rating must be a number between 0 and 5'
).isInt({ min: 0, max: 5 })
```

but only for integer numbers, not for decimals, and the input needs to be either a decimal or an integer number between `0` and `5`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 21):

`isNumeric` doesn't have a `min` and `max` values, you can use `isFloat` instead:

```
check('rating', 'Rating must be a number between 0 and 5')
  .isFloat({ min: 5, max: 5 })
```

You can read more about those methods in [validator.js docs](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#validators).

Comment: Your solution validates a float within a certain range, but the question is to validate an integer or a float within a certain range.

Answer (score 7):

for int check

```
 body('status', 'status value must be between 0 to 2')
      .isInt({ min: 0, max: 2 }),
```

Comment: Your solution validates an integer within a certain range but the question is to validate an integer or a float within a certain range.

Answer (score -1):

isNumeric and isFloat doesn't have a min and max values, you can use not() instead:

```
body("dialyPrice", "Daily price must be between 1000 to 5000").not().isNumeric({ min: 1000, max: 4000 }),
```

but only for integer numbers, not for decimals, and the input needs to be either a decimal or an integer number between 1000 and 4000.

Thank you.

Comment: isNumeric doesn't have min and max in the options, but isFloat indeed have min and max in the options.

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION**

It validates numbers in general, exactly as requested ("*an integer or a float within a certain range*")

```
body('rating')
    .exists({checkFalsy: true}).withMessage('You must type a rating')
    .custom((value, {req, location, path}) => {
        const {body: {rating}} = req;
        const ratingFloat = rating.toFixed(2);
        return ratingFloat >= 0 && ratingFloat <= 5
    }).withMessage("You must type a rating lower or equal than 5 & bigger or equal than 0"),
```